# How can I send results of a test as a parameter to my python script?

Tags: python, cypress

I created a scheduled task and my cypress script is being run once an hour. But after that I want to execute a python script and pass the result data there.

Run the script and get the "results" as failed or success.

```
$ cypress run --spec "cypress/integration/myproject/myscript.js"
```

And pass the "results" data to a python script.

```
$ python test.py results
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module which is able to run external commands, here is the example:

```py
import subprocess

def get_test_output():
    filepath = './cypress/integration/myproject/myscript.js'

    res = subprocess.run(
        ['echo', filepath],
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
    )
    # In your case it will be:
    # res = subprocess.run(
    #     ['cypress', 'run', '--spec', filepath],
    #     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    #     stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
    # )

    return res.stdout.decode()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_res = get_test_output()

    print(test_res)
    # => ./cypress/integration/myproject/myscript.js
```

You could run `cypress` in the begining of `test.py` and pass results further to needed functions